# Redshift regexp match

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

There are values in a column like these

```
NEW_COLUMN
abcd-2020-ab1-01
abcd-2020-ab2-010
abcd-2021-ab1-020
abcd-2021-ab2-125
abcd-2021-ab2-126 abcd-2021-ab2-126 abcd-2021-ab2-126 -- matches all of them
abcd-2021-ab2-126-BC-DEG -- fails to match
```

**Problem**

I'm able to match the first 4 records correctly.

1. With 5th one, it gets all instances. However I wish to get just the first one.
2. If I extend my regexp to match this one, the original one fails to match. Is there a way do an 'OR' kind of match in regexp? Like match the first pattern or the second one.

**My Code**

```
select my_column, regexp_substr(my_column,'[[:word:]]{4}\-(.*)\-[[:digit:]]{1,4}') as extracted
from my_table
```

To solve first point I have tried using `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)` but redshift throws error as it does not support that. Any workaround will be helpful

**Explanation of regex**

`[[:word:]]{4}` - Finds first 4 characters

`\-` - finds `-`

`(.*)` - finds everything until next `-`

`\-` - finds `-`

`[[:digit:]]{1,4}` - finds digits between 0 to 4 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to match the first string and then only consider your pattern as a prefix:

```
regexp_substr(my_column, '^[[:word:]]{4}\-([^ ]*)\-[[:digit:]]{1,4}[^ ]*')
```

Comment: This still gives multiple instances. (row 5 in my example)

Comment: @PirateX . .. I don't see how that is possible.  The `^` anchors the pattern to the beginning of the string.  Only one pattern can match that . . . and I don't think Redshift has redefined regular expressions.

Comment: So the reason why it's still showing up is because of `(.*)`. It matches everything in between a word of 4 char and digit of 4 char. Since row 5 still matches this pattern, all of them show up

Comment: @PirateX . . . That is a good catch.  I replaced that with `[^ ]*` -- although you might have something else in mind.

Comment: Replacing it with `[^ ]`, results in a blank match

Comment: @PirateX . . . I meant to only replace the `.` with `[^ ]` but accidentally removed the `*` as well.

Comment: Works like a charm! Marked as correct answer. Also, can you explain why `[^ ]` solves this problem?

Comment: @PirateX . . . Because it anchors the pattern to the beginning of the string.  That only allows one match.